# IE 11 doesn't load JS script (removes it from its list of scripts in developer tools)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

(All other browsers including Edge work fine)

I have a script A.js and B.js.

They're both loaded:

```
<script src="/scripts/A.js?20191031012417" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/B.js?20191031011942" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(I tried also without date querystrings)

However, in Developer tools script B.js dissapears after split second, and A.js is loaded (listed) twice!
Of course, methods from script B.js are missing and the app cracks.

I tried pasting code from stript B.js to the end of A.js.
It works.

However, it is necessary that the code should be placed in separate file B.js.

[image]
[image]

Comment: ie 11 is an old browser and contains many conflicts like this, if you want a tip, create a condition if it is navigator ie11 load another JS (contains both js).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that illustrates this issue?

Comment: i can't reproduce this impossibility

Comment: @Ahmed: I have conditional loading, this is just simplification of my problem. To all: I can't give you an example, it's a part of huge project. However I'll try to post captures of Developer tools

Comment: @Dalibor If you can produce a Minimal Veriviable Code Example it might be that you debug it yourself by reproducing it.  We cannot help without something to play with.

Comment: I'm sorry I cant give you code because both player.prototype.js (A file) and playerApi.prestoplayer.js (B file) are huge. However, when I cut and paste code from B file into A file, it works fine.

Comment: i had several questions, 1) do your IE run under compatibility mode; 2) is the mime type for the js file correct; 3) are you using ecmascript somewhere; 4) any error message in the console?. this is a pretty broad issue, which sadly people cant trivially reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: Thanks. 1) No, 2) Yes, 3) Yes, ES6, but it works when in file A, not B; 4) No. Only error is missing methods from script B that are not loaded (since script B is not loaded)

Comment: Is there an execution order in the A.js and B.js script? whether they will call the function from another files, such as: B.js will call the function from A.js? For the B.js script reference, try to add the [defer attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp), thus, we could run it until after the page has loaded.

Comment: Good thinking. But, sadly, it didn't help. I tried using defer on A.js, on B.js and on both. Still the same bug.

Comment: I found the (semi)-solution, I wrote the answer. Thank you all, especially Zhi Lv and Bagus Tesa,

Answer (score 0):

I guess some are intrigued with this stange bug, so I'll post the workaround that I did. I'm not saying "solution" and I'm not saying that I understand what's going on, I'm just saying I realized what code IE decides to ignore so bad, that it doesn't load the whole script:

The method "play" in playerApi.prestoplayer.js looks like this:

```
play: function (url) {
    var promise = this.player.play();
    if (promise !== undefined) {
        promise.then(() => {
            // Autoplay started...
        });
    }
},
```

And if I have it, the script wouldn't load! Now get this: If I comment promise.then... then IE decides to load script after all!!

```
play: function (url) {
    var promise = this.player.play();
    if (promise !== undefined) {
        //promise.then(() => {
        //   // Autoplay started...
        //});
    }
},
```

**If I didn't stress it enough, method play() is never nearly called! It is just defined in the script, waititng to be called!**

Now get this:

If I write something totaly crazy like this:

```
play: function (url) {
    var promise = this.player.play();
    if (promise !== undefined) {
        xrtgrtgjtwrohjoirjthoojqtreoqoeigjoiqeo
    }
},
```

**it is fine by IE! It loads the script, it doesn't mind this syntax error. But If I use *"xxxx.then"* in script, the IE doesn't want to load that script!!!**

Hope this helps someone and save their nerves, time, money, maritual status etc.